# How can I rotate a 'sidewaysfigure'?

Tags: rotating

I would like to rotate my`sidewaysfigure` to face towards the left rather than the right (i.e. from 90 degreed to 270 degrees). Does anyone know how I can do this using the `sidewaysfigure` environment?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating}
%\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}
    \caption{text here}
    \label{fig:mine}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just the image, or the caption as well? Do you want this globally, or just for a single image?

Answer (score 8):

To have the bottom edge of the figures be placed on the left, load the `rotating` package with the option `figuresleft`. By the way, this option affects the orientation of `sidewaysfigures` *and* `sidewaystables`, not just of `sidewaysfigures`.

Incidentally, since the `rotating` package loads the `graphicx` package automatically, there's no need to load `graphicx` separately.

---

*Addendum*: If you want the orientation of the `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable` environments to alternate between odd-numbered and even-numbered pages, do not specify either `figuresleft` or `figuresright`. Instead, use the *document class option* `twoside` -- or use a document class, such as `book`, that invokes the `twoside` option by default. That said, I suspect that your readers might strongly dislike having to crane their necks first to one side and then to the other to take in your figures. Better to stick with a single orientation...

Comment: thanks! this still hasn't really solved my problem though.. I want to do exactly what you said, have two images on two pages face the same direction (e.g. left and right page figures facing towards the right), but when I have a single image on it's own, I want it to face outward towards the left on the left page and vise vursa..

Comment: @Michael - If you want to go the route of having different orientations depending on whether there's a figure on both pages or on just one page of a two-page spread, what kind of information will you be supplying so that LaTeX can figure out which case applies? By the way, I still don't think your readers are going to appreciate having to crane their necks in one direction or another depending on whether there's a single sidewaysfigure on either the left-hand side or the right-hand side of a two-page layout.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

**Code 1**

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{sideways}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{bear}
  \end{sideways}
  \centering
  \caption[Caption]{Bear}
  \label{pic:picture}
\end{figure}
```

**Result 1**
[image]

**Code 2**

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{turn}{-90}
  \begin{minipage}{3in}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{bear}
  \caption{Bear}
  \label{fig:bear}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{turn}
\end{figure}
```

**Result 2**
[image]

Sure you can mix and use what you want! Hope it helps

Comment: You can leave the caption out as in the first example. Do whatever you want but this should achieve what you need!

Comment: Thanks Odin! the image has now rotated fine, but the caption has not and is at the bottom of the page, even when using code 2. I exactly have the same code as code 2 in my document, except my scale = 0.6 and minipage = 0.8in. Before this, the image would be underneath some text on the following pages..

Comment: As you described it, it's a matter of scaling to fit. If you can share real code and image I would help you more but now hard to tell.

Comment: Also mined the specifiers in `\begin{figure}`. [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures) are what they exactly do.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\begin{document}

\hvFloat[objectAngle=90]{figure}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}}%
    {text here}%
    {fig:mine}%

\hvFloat[objectAngle=90,capAngle=90,capPos=right]{figure}{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{example-image-a}}%
{text here}%
{fig:mine2}%

\end{document}
```

[image]